# Axios sending post request with my own cookie

Tags: axios, httpclient

I'm trying do send post request with cookie. In postman it works fine when in 'Headers' section I will get

```
Cookie = 'ssoLang=en;wt3_eid=%343632BJ335*;usave=c8-0c-fb-45-98-2a'
```

but how I can add this cookie in axios, I can't see that option in 'config'

What I send is:

```
axios.post ('https://mypage/service/data', 'myPayload', {withCredentials:true, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

I tried to add my cookie into headers like below but it didn't work.

```
axios.post ('https://mypage/service/data', 'myPayload', {withCredentials:true, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cookie':Cookie}})
```

Can someone help with this please?

Comment: How to you know it does not work ? Maybe try doing it against https://www.toptal.com/developers/postbin/ or something similar and validate that the Cookie header is sent correctly.

Comment: You can also try to  set cookie in js like `document.cookie = ""`

Comment: I ran it in my code where I'm getting 500 in return

Comment: I think your code looks ok. You could be getting 500 for other reasons as well. That's why you have to investigate further. For example to the request against the post bin thing I sent so you can see if you are not doing wrong assumptions